# How can I convert SAS data files into something simple like CSV data?

Tags: conversion, csv, xml

There are government data files available from [this CDC web site](https://web.archive.org/web/20090308042359/http://www.cdc.gov/EpiInfo/), but they are in a weird SAS format.

How can I convert them into XML/CSV, i.e. something much simpler that can be read by scripts, etc?

Comment: Is http://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/health_statistics/NCHS/Datasets/NSFG/sas/1995FemPregInput.sas an example of the SAS files you're looking at?  CDC seems to use this extension for code as well as data.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~mlf/SAS-Parser-0.93/lib/SAS/Parser.pm deals with them

Comment: SAS is an integrated programming/data management tool.  Unless specifically done otherwise, the code & data are stored in the same file/type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**StatTransfer**](http://www.stattransfer.com) will convert SAS files to a variety of formats and it includes options to filter variables or observations, customize the delimiter, and change variable storage formats during the transfer.

[**AM**](http://am.air.org) will also covert data, but it's less powerful/flexible.  AM is freeware and written for Windows.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [R-cran](http://cran.r-project.org/), if you have SAS `xpt` files. Use the `foreign` and `hmisc` packages.

```
xpt = sasxport.get("xpt/DEMO.xpt")
write.csv(xpt, file="demo.csv")
```

Comment: What's R-cran? Maybe you could add a link to this?

Comment: the R-project open source statistical software. Added a link.

Comment: R 3.2.3 Windows. I did the following:
`library('foreign')`
`data = read.xport("C:\\Users\\x\\Downloads\\aaa.XPT")`
`write.csv(data, file="C:\\Users\\x\\Downloads\aaa.csv)`

Answer (score 4):

SAS Institute (the company that makes SAS) produces a [viewer for SAS data sets](http://www.sas.com/apps/demosdownloads/sassysview_PROD_8.2_sysdep.jsp?packageID=000176).

Note that SAS program files usually have the extension `.sas`, whereas the data files themselves usually have the extension `.sas7bdat`.

Comment: Does this program perform a conversion? How does this answer the question?

Comment: It seems it can export to csv http://scriptogr.am/richie/post/convert-sas7bdat-to-csv

Answer (score 2):

You can extract data from .SAS7BDAT files using dsread from Oceanview Consultancy, see

http://www.oview.co.uk/dsread

It handles files from most platforms though may require registration for some platforms.  It's a fast and easy-to-use command-line Windows program that also runs under Wine on Linux. No installation required, just run the .exe.

I realise that this is an old question but it shows up in relevant web searches so including this answer will help anyone else looking to extract data from the proprietary SAS7BDAT format.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of dsread.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about SAS XPT files, you can use the [`xport`](https://github.com/selik/xport) Python module.

```
import xport

with open('example.xpt', 'rb') as f:
    for row in xport.Reader(f):
        print row
```